# Frama-c - Problem with proving "assigns" until strlen

Tags: frama-c

I have a problem with proving `assigns` after calling other function that assigns until strlen. Below is a simple example with a call to a function from standard library. The function contract is basically a copy from `strcpy` requirements.

```c
#include <string.h>

/*@ 
    requires valid_string_src: valid_read_string(src);
    requires room_string: \valid(dest+(0..strlen(src)));

    requires separation:
      \separated(dest+(0..strlen(src)), src+(0..strlen(src)));

    assigns dest[0..(strlen(src))];

  */
void mycpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    strcpy(dest, src);
}
```

Frama-c fails to prove `assigns` for mycpy even though it matches `assigns` of the strcpy:

```ml
Goal Assigns ... (exit):
Let a_0 = « dest@L1 + 0 ».
Let x_0 = L_strlen(µ:Mchar@L1, src@L1).
Let x_1 = 1 + x_0.
Let x_2 = L_strlen(Mchar_0, src@L1).
Assume {
  Have: 0 <= x_2.
  Type: is_sint8_chunk(µ:Mchar@L1).
  (* Heap *)
  Type: (region(dest@L1.base) <= 0) /\ (region(src@L1.base) <= 0) /\
      linked(µ:Malloc@L1) /\ sconst(µ:Mchar@L1).
  (* Goal *)
  When: !invalid(µ:Malloc@L1, a_0, 1 + x_2).
  Stmt { L1:  }
  (* Pre-condition *)
  Have: P_valid_read_string(µ:Malloc@L1, µ:Mchar@L1, src@L1) /\
      valid_rw(µ:Malloc@L1, a_0, x_1) /\
      separated(a_0, x_1, « src@L1 + 0 », x_1).
}
Prove: x_2 <= x_0.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prover Alt-Ergo 2.3.3: Timeout (Qed:6ms) (10s) (cached).
```

The full context of the goal shows that it tries to prove: `L_strlen(Mchar_0, src@L1) <= L_strlen(µ:Mchar@L1, src@L1)`. However, there is no information about `Mchar_0`.

What is this `µ:Mchar@L1` and `Mchar_0`? How do I prove this assigns?

Frama-c version: 22.0 (Titanium).

Comment: It seems to be due to a bug related to memory labels.

Comment: FYI, this issue is fixed on the public development version of Frama-C. It will be available in the next stable version.